# Save css classes when refreshing with jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make a navigation with jquery that has 3 simple pages. 
The point is to not needing to reload the page when switching to another page in the navigation.

It simply does fadeIn and fadeOut for divs. Works great. 
Problem is I want to save the position of the page when reloading. 
I have a class that's called isVisible that gets added so I thought I could do it through that.
Anybody have an idea how to do it?

This is my js that get's executed when the page is loaded.
otherwise it only changes when clicking in the navigation

```
    $('.skills').hide();
    $('.work').hide();
    $('.about').hide();
    $('.contact').hide();

    $('.nav-about').addClass('isVisible');
    $('.about').fadeIn(100);
```

I thought through url parameters but using them with javascript/jquery is pretty complicated

Comment: Implement the history api.

Comment: or keep track of the current url using anchors i.e. `http://yourdomain/page.html#work`

Comment: Can jquery read anchors and act on them?

Answer (score 1):

You should use cookies to save the state of the page.
You can check this: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie